# Создание запароленного KeyStore

Tags: java, android, криптография

Подскажите как сделать запароленный KeyStore для ключей шифрования? Знаю, что это возможно, но не знаю каким параметром он задаётся.

Генерирую ключи шифрования и одновременно создаю KeyStore так:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator .getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new  KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            alias,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT |     PURPOSE_SIGN | PURPOSE_VERIFY  )
            .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
            .setKeySize(4096)
            .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PSS)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
            .build();
    generator.initialize(spec);
}
KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()); //создаем объект KeyStore
ks.load(null, "password".toCharArray()); //задаем пароль

// создаем внешний файл
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("KeyStoreFileName");
//пишем KeyStore
ks.store(fos, password);
fos.close();
```

Comment: То есть ключи будут храниться в этом файле или в самом KeyStore?

Comment: Файл есть образ `KeyStore` на диске, то есть они идентичны с точки зрения контента